# Google Calendar API how to find attendee list

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I need to find attendee list for a meeting using Google Calendar API. To extract attendee email, I have below code:

```
eventsResult = service.events().list(calendarId='primary',timeMin=tmin,timeMax=tmax,singleEvents=True,orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = eventsResult.get('items', [])

for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            end = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))
            attendees = event['attendees'].get('email', event['attendees'].get('email'))
            print(attendees)
```

But getting error

```
attendees = event['attendees'].get('email', event['attendees'].get('email'))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What am I missing? Any suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: you're trying to get an attribute value from a list. Did you mean to get the value from a specific item in the list?

Comment: @ADysonnot sure what you meant. I guess I am not accessing it the right way.

Comment: "event['attendees']" is a list of attendees. Within the list are one or more attendees. The **list** object does not have a property called "email". Each of the **individual items within the list** does. If you want to get the email for a particular attendee, you have to reference that specific item in the list, not the whole list. I don't know python syntax, but `event['attendees'].get` is clearly trying to read directly from the list and not from any particular item. If you want to get all the emails, you probably have to loop through the attendees list and extract each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the solution yet, how about this? The structure of `attendees` is as follows.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "attendees": [
        {
          "email": "### email ###",
          "displayName": "### name ###",
          "responseStatus": "#####"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So how about this modification?

#### From :

```
for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            end = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))
            attendees = event['attendees'].get('email', event['attendees'].get('email'))
            print(attendees)
```

#### To :

```
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    end = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))
    print("{0}, {1}".format(start, end))
    for attendee in event['attendees']:
        attendees = attendee.get('email', attendee.get('email'))
        print(attendees)
```

If I misunderstand your question and you already have the solution, I'm sorry.

Comment: I try it, but if event doesnt have attendees, key error, so how to check event have attendee or not?

Comment: @Linh Nguyễn Ngọc At first, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And also, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I try it, but if event doesnt have attendees, key error, so how to check event have attendee or not?`. So can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, it will help users think of the solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Comment: Thank you, i change the logic, when i have eventId, i will try to use GET API, not LIST API, LIST API dont support 'attendees', so when use FOR loop, we have to use GET API again :)

Comment: @Linh Nguyễn Ngọc Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I apologize that I was not useful.

Comment: yeah, i already up my code in the answer, i hope it is usefull for anyone

Answer (score 0):

I hope this i solution, this function to get attendee by email or calendar ID of attendee, result list event of attendees email

```
def get_events_by_attendee(service, calendarId, attendee_email):
    now = datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    timeMin = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=3) #you can change
    timeMax = datetime.utcnow()+ timedelta(days=3)#you can change
    print(timeMin, now)
    timeMin = timeMin.isoformat() + 'Z'
    timeMax = timeMax.isoformat() + 'Z'
    print(timeMin)

    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=calendarId,
                                          timeMin=timeMin,
                                          timeMax = timeMax,
                                          singleEvents=True,
                                          orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    list_events = []
    for event1 in events:
        element_list = []
        eventId = event1['id']
        event = service.events().get(calendarId=calendarId, eventId=eventId).execute() #check this event have attendee or not
        try:

            if event['attendees']:
                for attendee in event['attendees']:
                    if (attendee['email']==attendee_email)and(attendee['responseStatus']=='accepted'): #responseStatus 'accept' mean attendee accept your invitation
                        print(event['attendees'])
                        element_list.append(eventId)
                        htmlLink = event['htmlLink']
                        element_list.append(htmlLink)
                        summary = event['summary']
                        element_list.append(summary)
                        try: #this code belong to my sytems, you can pass it
                            description = event['description']
                            description = description.replace('\n', '<br>')
                            description = description.split('####', 1)
                            if description == []:
                                description = event['description']
                        except Exception as e:
                            description = 'Không có mô tả####'
                            description = description.split('####', 1)
                        element_list.append(description)
                        created = event['created']
                        created = dateutil.parser.parse(created) + timedelta(hours=7) #change the timezone
                        created = datetime(created.year, created.month, created.day, created.hour, created.minute)
                        element_list.append(created)
                        updated = event['updated']
                        updated = dateutil.parser.parse(updated) + timedelta(hours=7)#change the timezone
                        updated = datetime(updated.year, updated.month, updated.day, updated.hour, updated.minute)
                        element_list.append(updated)
                        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
                        start = dateutil.parser.parse(start) + timedelta(hours=7)#change the timezone
                        start = datetime(start.year, start.month, start.day, start.hour, start.minute)
                        element_list.append(start)
                        end = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))
                        end = dateutil.parser.parse(end) + timedelta(hours=7)
                        end = datetime(end.year, end.month, end.day, end.hour, end.minute)
                        element_list.append(end)
                        status = event['status']
                        element_list.append(status)
                        attendees = event['attendees']
                        element_list.append(attendees)
                        list_events.append(element_list)
                    else:
                        pass
        except Exception as e:
            pass
    return list_events
```