# Get attendees email from Google Calendar API - Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to extract the emails from all Google Calendar events. I've been following other links ([Google Calendar API how to find attendee list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231442/google-calendar-api-how-to-find-attendee-list)) but I'm getting an error

```
attendees = event['attendees'].get('email', event['attendees'].get('email'))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This is the code

```
for event in events:

        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        end = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))
        attendees = event['attendees'].get('email', event['attendees'].get('email'))
        print(attendees)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `get()` on a list which I'm guessing `event['attendees']` is. You have multiple way of handling this. You can loop through the `event['attendees']` and get the email from each individual attendee. You could also use map() to do the same thing

forEach Loop example:

```
event['attendees'].forEach(attendee => console.log(attendee.get('email')))
```

map example:

```
const attendees = event['attendees'].map(attendee => attendee.get('email'))
```